# How to replace garbled characters in a string?

Tags: php, char, utf

I have this text...

> â€œIâ€™m not trying to be credible,â€ David admits with a smile broadening"

...and I would like to delete those funny characters, I've tried `str_replace()` but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is an underlying problem that you should fix.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have handled text in a different encoding then its source encoding.

So if the text is UTF-8, you are not handling it currently as UTF-8. The easiest way is to send a header such as...

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

You could also add the `meta` element, but ensure it is the first child of your `head` element.

You need to fix that at the source instead of trying to patch it later (which will never work well).

Comment: Couldn't it also be the `content-type` of the displaying page?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That would be handling text in a different encoding :)

Comment: I don't understand your comment... I had the same problem as the OP when copying/pasting from Word files, and fixed them (typically) by changing to `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: That would be changing from handling one text encoding as another to handling the text encoding with the correct encoding. That is what I was trying to say in the answer.

Comment: Ooohhh. Alright, that makes sense. But maybe your answer could be more specific?

Comment: I agree that searching and replacing only induces insanity and "*why oh why*"'s.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

Different sources often have different encodings, so you need to specify the encoding in which you are presenting the view. Utf-8 is the most popular, since it covers all of ASCII and many, many other languages.

php's utf8_(de)encode converts iso-8859-1 to utf-8 and the opposite and regular string manipulating functions are not multibyte-(which utf-8 can be) character aware. Either you use functions specific to mb_strings or enable encoding with certain parameters.

//comment if i'm mistaken

Comment: You should consider describing _why_ this code will help. Yes, it will probably solve the Question, but the Question is worded such that they don't know that they need this fix; explain why they do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are using a different character encoding that you should probably use(you should be using utf-8 encoding), so I would change that instead of trying to just fix it on the spot with a quick-fix(you will run into less problems overall that way).

---

If you really want to fix it using PHP, you can use the ctype_alpha() function; you should be able to do something like this:

```
$theString = "your text here"; // your input string

$newString = ""; // your new string
$i = 0;
while($theString[$i]) // while there are still characters in the string
{
    if(ctype_alpha($theString[$i]) // if it's a character in your current set
    { 
       $newString .= $theString[$i]; // add it to the new string, increment pointer, and go to next loop iteration
       $i++;
       continue; 
    } // if the specific character at the $i index is an alphabetical character, add it to the new string
    else
    {
       $i++;
    } // if it's a bad character, just move the pointer up by one for the next iteration
}
```

Then use $newString however you want to. Really though, just change your character encoding instead of doing it this way. You want the encoding to be the same across your entire project.